# Replacing StretchDIBits with GDI+ (while drawing an Image to Printer's canvas)

Tags: delphi, winapi, image-processing, gdi+, delphi-6

My application is developed in Delphi 6. This is a resource intesive application due to background processing and large volume of data (It consumes around 60MB - 120MB of physical memory). One of the functionality of this application is to create barcode images and print them.  If user keeps on generating the Barcodes, then at least One out of Ten Barcode has missing lines in it.

I was able to resolve this issue using TExcellenImagePrinter component. But, it diminished the performance a lot. This resolution was rejected by my client and hence, now I am trying to replace the WinAPI StretchDIBits call with GDI+.

The original source code is as following:

```
procedure PrintBitmap(ARect:TRect; Bitmap:TBitmap);
var
   Info: PBitmapInfo;
   InfoSize: dword{Integer};
   Image: Pointer;
   ImageSize: dword{ integer};
   iWidth,iHeight :integer;
   iReturn : integer ;
begin
   GetDIBSizes(Bitmap.handle,InfoSize,ImageSize);
   if (LoadDIBFromTBitmap(Bitmap,Pointer(Info),Image,iWidth,iHeight)) then
   begin
        SetStretchBltMode(Printer.Canvas.handle,STRETCH_HALFTONE);
        SetBrushOrgEx(Printer.Canvas.handle, 0, 0, NIL);
        iReturn := StretchDIBits(Printer.Canvas.Handle, ARect.Left, ARect.Top,
            ARect.Right - ARect.Left, ARect.Bottom - ARect.Top,
            0, 0, Info^.bmiHeader.biWidth,
            Info^.bmiHeader.biHeight, Image, Info^,DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
   end;
   FreeMemEx(Info);
   FreeMemEx(Image);
end;
```

I got the GDI+ header from the (http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=7) as suggested by Joe in embarcadero forums (https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=471501#471501).

I have modified my source code as following :

- Created an object of TGPGraphics class and assigned the printer's handle to it.

  gp := TGPGraphics.Create(Printer.Canvas.Handle);
- Created an onject of TGPBitmap class and assigned the barcode image to it.

  bmp := TGPBitmap.Create(Info^,Image);

  Info is TBitmapInfo and Image is an pointer.
- Assigned the Printer's dimension to the an instance **rect** of TGPRect record
- Called the DrawImage function :

  gp.DrawImage(bmp,rect);

But, after making these changes, empty image is shown in the printer's output.
Can you point out if I have missed something or my implementation is wrong.
Can you provide any pointers regarding this?

Comment: I asked a similar question @ stackoverflow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869886/processing-barcode-image-with-delphi-6-using-stretchdibits-missing-bar-lines-i)

Comment: Looking at your previous q, did you ensure that the code  drawing the original bitmap is correct? Printers are normally higher resolution than screens so I would not expect lines to disappear, maybe get wider but not disappear, unless they were 1 pixel wide which would not be scan-able anyway with modern printer resolutions... Also with anything that needs accuracy such as barcodes I would not trust any general purpose bitmap scaling function. They work fine for pictures but are awful with say text.

Comment: @Despatcher : yes. I have checked that the original code to generate the barcode image is working fine. Apart from StretchDIBits, I tried to use TExcellentImagePrinter component but, the performance was decreased by 10 times. Any suggestions regarding third party tools compatible with Delphi 6?

Comment: As I implied - I think you should scale the drawing routine so it can draw directly to the printer canvas... That's what I ended up doing for something similar. So you would have routine called something like DrawBarcode(ACanvas, X, Y, Width, Height, HorizontalResolution, VerticalResolution).

Comment: @Despatcher : Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this out ans used DrawRectangle to draw each BarLine. But, still this issue was replicable. Also, the performance of the system was impacted e.g. using StretchDIBits, the entire process was taking 3ms but, now it takes ~25 ms.

Comment: Have you tried to use it like in [`this example`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533891(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: @TLama : Yes, my implementation is similar to the provided example. There was some problem in co-ordinates and I was able to solve it. But, my problem stated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869886/processing-barcode-image-with-delphi-6-using-stretchdibits-missing-bar-lines-i?lq=1 is not solved :(

Comment: @Abhineet Have you been able to solve the problem by now?

Comment: @John : The problem of using GDI+ was solved very early. But, the problem mentioned in above comment was solved very recently. We used barcode fonts and GDI+ to draw barcodes. Removed the dependency from StretchDIBits winAPI call. Thanks for your concern and do provide your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following code demonstrating creation of compatible bitmap (DBB) from a dib.
That should work for you. Probably it could be written better but all in all it just works ... at least for me..

```
procedure PRPrintBitmapOnCanvas(Canvas: TMetafileCanvas; Bitmap: TBitmap; posLeft, posTop: Integer);
var
  lpbmih: TBitmapInfoHeader;
  lpbmi: TBitmapInfo;
  aBitmap: HBITMAP;
  aDC: LongWord;
begin
  Fillchar(lpbmih, SizeOf(lpbmih), 0);
  lpbmih.biSize := SizeOf(lpbmih);
  lpbmih.biWidth := bitmap.width;
  lpbmih.biHeight := bitmap.height;
  lpbmih.biPlanes := 1;
  lpbmih.biBitCount := 32;
  lpbmih.biCompression := BI_RGB;

  Fillchar(lpbmi, SizeOf(lpbmi), 0);
  lpbmi.bmiHeader.biSize := SizeOf(lpbmi.bmiHeader);
  lpbmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes := 1;
  lpbmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount := 32;
  lpbmi.bmiHeader.biCompression := BI_RGB;

  aBitmap := CreateDIBitmap(Canvas.Handle, lpbmih, 0, nil, lpbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
  if aBitmap = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    aDC := CreateCompatibleDC(Canvas.Handle);
    SelectObject(aDC, aBitmap);

    BitBlt(aDC, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    BitBlt(canvas.handle, posLeft, posTop, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, aDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    DeleteDC(aDC);
  finally
    DeleteObject(aBitmap)
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question asked, which was how to use GDI+ to draw the bitmap to the Printer.Canvas.

Comment: Yep, but it gives the answer how to avoid 3rd party commercial components like mentioned TExcellenImagePrinter to print out the bitmap using bitmap compatible DDB with device context. I had the same problem with printing (blanck page), StretchDIBits hadn't worked either. DDB is an option which seems to work for most printers' drivers.